# PHP: Turning multidimensional arrays to single dimension arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Basically my app is interacting with a web service that sends back a weird multidimensional array such as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Price] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Size] => 7
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Type] => 2
        )
)
```

That's not a problem, but the problem is that the service keeps changing the index of those items, so in the next array the Price could be at 1 instead of 0.

How do I effeciently transform arrays like this into a single dimension array so I can access the variables through $var['Size'] instead of $var[1]['Size']?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
$result = array();

foreach($array as $inner) {
    $result[key($inner)] = current($inner);        
}
```

The `$result` array would now look like this:

```
Array
(
    [Price] => 1
    [Size] => 7
    [Type] => 2
)
```

Comment: If it's 3 dimensions this doesn't go deep enough.

Answer (score 30):

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

Comment: Note that this requires that the second-level array key names are not identical. Otherwise, they will be merged, returning a single result only.

Answer (score 7):

I am using laravel's helper: http://laravel.com/api/source-function-array_flatten.html#179-192

```
function array_flatten($array)
    {
        $return = array();

        array_walk_recursive($array, function($x) use (&$return) { $return[] = $x; });

        return $return;
    }
```

Comment: This works, even with 3+ dimensional arrays Such Solution!

Answer (score 4):

```
function flattenArray($input, $maxdepth = NULL, $depth = 0)
{
    if(!is_array($input)){ 
      return $input;
    }

    $depth++;
    $array = array(); 
    foreach($input as $key=>$value){
      if(($depth <= $maxdepth or is_null($maxdepth)) && is_array($value)){
        $array = array_merge($array, flattenArray($value, $maxdepth, $depth));
      } else {
        array_push($array, $value);
        // or $array[$key] = $value;
      }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider $mArray as multidimensional array and $sArray as single dimensional array this code will ignore the parent array

```
function flatten_array($mArray) {
    $sArray = array();

    foreach ($mArray as $row) {
        if ( !(is_array($row)) ) {
            if($sArray[] = $row){
            }
        } else {
            $sArray = array_merge($sArray,flatten_array($row));
        }
    }
    return $sArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i found best solution to this :

```
array_walk_recursive($yourOLDmultidimarray, function ($item, $key) {
    //echo "$key holds $item\n";
$yourNEWarray[]=$item;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use php >= 5.6, you may use array unpacking (it's much faster):

```
$result = array_merge(...$array);
```

See [wiki.php.net on unpacking](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking)