# PHP get array child

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to change last child of array (122) with second child of array (0). You can see with samples. Please help me.

Current version:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [122] => Array
                (
                    [PROGRAM_ID] => 181
                    [VENUE_ID] => 2
                    [AUDIT_ID] => 96
                )

        )

)
```

I want this:

```
Array
(
    [122] => Array
        (
            [PROGRAM_ID] => 181
            [VENUE_ID] => 2
            [AUDIT_ID] => 96
        )

)
```

Comment: $myarray = $myarray[0];

Comment: It works for only one child. I have hundreds of array values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for something like this....

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2408971/1172872

Like this:

```
$result = array();

foreach($array as $inner) {
    $result[key($inner)] = current($inner);        
}
```

The `$result` array would now look like this:

```
Array
(
    [122] => Array
    (
        [PROGRAM_ID] => 181
        [VENUE_ID] => 2
        [AUDIT_ID] => 96
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works fine `$array = reset($array);` for the first child and `$array = end($array);` for the last.