# Merge multi dimensional PHP array with in

Tags: php, arrays, merge

My question is a little different from similar posts, in a sense that I don't have any other array to merge with.

I want to merge arrays with in multi-dimensional array.

So that it's not a multi dimensional any more.

Here is the array I have:

```
Array
(
    [2013-12-01::2015-07-29] => Array
        (
            [TotalMonths] => 1
            [0] => 2015-07-01
        )

    [2015-11-01::2016-03-30] => Array
        (
            [TotalMonths] => 5
            [0] => 2015-11-01
            [1] => 2015-12-01
            [2] => 2016-01-01
            [3] => 2016-02-01
            [4] => 2016-03-01
        )

    [2016-04-01::2017-11-30] => Array
        (
            [TotalMonths] => 3
            [0] => 2016-04-01
            [1] => 2016-05-01
            [2] => 2016-06-01
        )

)
```

What I am trying is merging all arrays with in. But the index (TotalMonths) is common so only for that it should sum values like `(1+5+3) = 8` which will be reflected in new merged array.

I have tried [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408892/php-turning-multidimensional-arrays-to-single-dimension-arrays) also, but I am not sure how I am getting same values.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
print_r($collidingMonths);
$outPutArray = array();
foreach($collidingMonths as $innerArray) {
    $outPutArray[key($innerArray)] = current($innerArray);
}

print_r($outPutArray);
```

But I am getting a result that I don't want:

```
Array
(
    [TotalMonths] => 3
)
```

Comment: `$outPutArray[key($innerArray)] = current($innerArray);`  why you are using `current` ?

Comment: what is your desired output look like??? I mean output array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight-forward way would be to take the `TotalMonths` value out of the array elements before merging:

```
$result = [];
$totalMonths = 0;
foreach($collidingMonths as $innerArray) {
    $TotalMonths += $innerArray['TotalMonths'];
    unset($innerArray['TotalMonths']);
    $result = array_merge($result, $innerArray);
}
```

=-=-==-=-=-=-

**UPDATE:**

Thanks, very nice work here. I had to do little changes. but all is your code.
Providing My Updated Code so might be helpful for some one.

**Updated Code**

```
        $outPutMonths = [];
        $TotalMonths = 0;
        foreach($collidingMonths as $innerArray) {
            $TotalMonths += $innerArray['TotalMonths'];
            unset($innerArray['TotalMonths']);
            $outPutMonths = array_merge($outPutMonths, $innerArray);
        }
        $outPutMonths['TotalMonths'] = $TotalMonths;
```

**Updated Result (Desired Result) :**

```
Array
(
[TotalMonths] => 9
[0] => 2015-07-01
[1] => 2015-11-01
[2] => 2015-12-01
[3] => 2016-01-01
[4] => 2016-02-01
[5] => 2016-03-01
[6] => 2016-04-01
[7] => 2016-05-01
[8] => 2016-06-01
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the expected output OP wants is:

```
array
(
    [TotalMonths] => 9,
    [0] => 2015-07-01,
    [1] => 2015-11-01,
    [2] => 2015-12-01,
    [3] => 2016-01-01,
    [4] => 2016-02-01,
    [5] => 2016-03-01,
    [6] => 2016-04-01,
    [7] => 2016-05-01,
    [8] => 2016-06-01,
)
```

To get that, we can do something like this:

```
$outPutArray = array();

foreach($collidingMonths as $timestamp => $monthsArray)
{
    foreach($monthsArray as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_numeric($value))
        {
            if(isset($outPutArray[$key]))
                $outPutArray[$key] += $value;
            else 
                $outPutArray[$key] = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            array_push($outPutArray, $value);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. Your answer is also great. I upvoted it.
But i selected @Sergey answer as he was the first to answer and he has only 1 foreach loop so i guess its more efficent.

But your code is working great too, which i have tested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `array_sum` and `array_column`. Let `$collidingMonths` as main array.

```
$arr2 = array_column($collidingMonths, 'TotalMonths');
echo array_sum($arr2);
```

**Result**

**Output Array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 3
)
```

**Sum:**

> 8